How can I load data sequentially into google BigQuery?
When I go to load my data frame data into 'BigQuery' the rows in the 'scSequence' column are messed up.

def load_table_from_dataframe(df, source_type):
    """
    Loads a pandas DataFrame into the specified BigQuery table.
    Adds a new column 'scSequence' with incremented row numbers based on the last row in the table.

    Args:
        df (pandas.DataFrame): The DataFrame to be loaded.
        source_type (str): The type of source (e.g., "RX", "MS").
    """
    table_id = f"{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET_ID}.{TABLE_MAPPING[source_type]}"

    df.insert(0, "scSequence", df.index + 1)

    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id)
    job.result()

    print(f"Data successfully loaded into {table_id}")

And this is an example of my data frame that I want to load into the BigQuery.

I want the rows in the 'scSequence' column to be sorted sequentially by using python code or any 'query'.
Here is an example what i want


Why do you need to add this sequence with df? Why do not you use a SQL query?

@guillaumeblaquiere Would you please share the SQL query it will be helpful for me.

perform your query and add ROW_NUMBER() over () as scSequence in the select. Store the result in a new table.
